# should we allow third-party question if they have bounty

Tags: discussion

I just looking in feature(bounty) section , where I find this below question

[Magmi Configurable Price](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150125/magmi-configurable-price)

This question is about the `Magami` the product importer tool. but this is also third party module.

So My question is that should we allow third party questions if they have bounty?...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot close questions while they have a bounty. When the bounty expires, you can treat it as any other question.

---

*But this particular question is not even closeworthy in my opinion. We should not blindly close anything 3rd party related!*

> 3) Can I write a script to loop through the configurable products and for each simple product grab it's price and set it as the price for that configuration?

*Especially this part can be answered without considering Magmi.*

Comment: Yes you are write with that point and in the answer you have given answer for that part only but out of this the other part of question is all about the Magmi

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we should allow them.
People offering their hard earned reputation points(which they got by being active here), so it would be kind of rude to close their questions.

Comment: Yes I feel same